# Explain a decompiled smart contract

Tags: solidity

I decompiled a smart contract with below link:

https://bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler

and I get these results:

```
def _fallback() payable: # default function
  if not call.value:
      mem[96 len calldata.size] = call.data[0 len calldata.size]
      _3 = 96, mem[96 len 21]
      _4 = mem[105]
      _5 = mem[106]
      mem[calldata.size + 96] = (Mask(8, -(('mask_shl', 256, 0, -3, ('mem', ('range', 106, 32))), 0) + 256, 31) << (('mask_shl', 256, 0, -3, ('mem', ('range', 106, 32))), 0) - 256) + 1
      mem[calldata.size + 128] = uint128(_3)
      mem[64] = calldata.size + (32 * (Mask(8, -(('mask_shl', 256, 0, -3, ('var', '_5')), 0) + 256, 31) << (('mask_shl', 256, 0, -3, ('var', '_5')), 0) - 256) + 2) + 336
      idx = 0
      s = calldata.size + 96
      t = 130
      while idx < Mask(8, -(('mask_shl', 256, 0, -3, ('var', '_5')), 0) + 256, 31) << (('mask_shl', 256, 0, -3, ('var', '_5')), 0) - 256:
          static call mem[t + 12 len 20] xor 2 * Mask(159, 0, uint128(_3) xor caller xor addr(_4)).getReserves() with:
                  gas gas_remaining wei
```

I didn't get what addresses this smart contract calls. The caller send some inputs then he use some encryption methods to encrypt addresses that he calls.

This is an input example:

```
0x986ea70205000000000000000001086a0271836f10bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c0319010000e04407f4ee70a7a86d24c8381d09af5126cc2259190000c8b6fc1555e2aa800d5b411489746bc03e6cfc458d190000001e3a283884d6b14183d7b3c2349c0cb87f7b23940000000000000000010ae4fa0af10f00
```

Can anyone help me to understand this piece of code?

Comment: Add a link to the original contract

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be calling a UniswapV2 pair `getReserves()` function.

With a link to the contract it would be easier to decode this.

Comment: How he encrypt and decrypt UniswapV2 pair addresses?

Comment: Post a link to the contract and I'll be able to check.

Comment: It's private project

Comment: Is it deployed to the blockchain?

Comment: yes. but I can't say it's address.